# How can i stop the Vue Nuxt dev server in the VS Code Console

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

Working with Vue Nuxt I start the dev server with "npm run dev".  How can I stop the Server afterwards from the VS Code console?  So far, the only way I found is closing the Terminal Window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Ctrl + c` you can stop the running dev server.